# Java duplicated Exception handling in a separate method

Tags: java, spring, error-handling

I work on a Spring webStart application...

I have 2 (and potentially more) methods that process multi-tier Exception clause, as in:

```
...
    try {
        employeeService.updateEmployeePartner(employeeId, partner);
        LOG.info("partner details updated for partner id {}", employeeId);
        result = new ResponseEntity<>(partner.getId(), HttpStatus.OK);
    } catch (EmployeePartnerNotFoundException ex) {
        LOG.error(ex.getMessage() + " employee id: ", employeeId);
        errorResponse = new ErrorResponse("500", ex.getMessage());
    } catch (ReadOperationDeniedException ex) {
        LOG.error("User doesn't have permissions to update employee's {} details: {}", employeeId, ex.getMessage());
        errorResponse = new ErrorResponse("403", "User doesn't have permissions to update employee's details");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        LOG.error("something went wrong while updating employee's {} partner details: {}", employeeId, ex.getMessage());
        errorResponse = new ErrorResponse("500", "unspecified server error");
    } finally {
        result = (result != null) ? result : new ResponseEntity<>(errorResponse, HttpStatus.I_AM_A_TEAPOT); // should be INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
    }
...
```

Another method is almost identical, apart for this change:
`employeeService.updateEmployeePartner(employeeId, partner);` =>
`employeeService.createEmployeePartner(employeeId, partner);`
and catching `EmployeePartnerAlreadyExistsException`  in that block.

Now, to reduce code duplication, I want to group all Error handling code in one place (method), so I replaced the above code with the following

```
...
        try {
            employeeService.updateEmployeePartner(employeeId, partner);
            LOG.info("partner details updated for partner id {}", employeeId);
            result = new ResponseEntity<>(partner.getId(), HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            errorResponse = processException(ex, employeeId, "update");
        } finally {
            result = (result != null) ? result : new ResponseEntity<>(errorResponse, HttpStatus.I_AM_A_TEAPOT); // should be INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
        }
...
    private ErrorResponse processException(Exception ex, Long employeeId, String operation) {
        ErrorResponse errorResponse;
        if (ex.getClass().equals(EmployeePartnerNotFoundException.class) ||
                ex.getClass().equals(EmployeePartnerExistsException.class)) {
            LOG.error(ex.getMessage() + " employee id: ", employeeId);
            errorResponse = new ErrorResponse("500", ex.getMessage());
        } else if (ex.getClass().isInstance(ReadOperationDeniedException.class)) {
            LOG.error("User doesn't have permissions to " + operation + " employee's {} details: {}", employeeId, ex.getMessage());
            errorResponse = new ErrorResponse("403", "User doesn't have permissions to " + operation + " employee's details");
        } else { // Exception
            LOG.error("something went wrong while trying to " + operation + "  employee's {} partner details: {}", employeeId, ex.getMessage());
            errorResponse = new ErrorResponse("500", "unspecified server error");
        }
        return errorResponse;
    }
```

Is that a good enough approach or are there any patterns to handle exceptions in the above scenario by outsourcing the handling to a separate method/class?

Since it's a spring application, I also consider using Spring exception handlers, as in:

```
 @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
```

, but that will only cover part of my requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use @ControllerAdvice with your custom ErrorResponse and each Handler for seprate exceptions. Refer [Custom error response Spring](http://www.baeldung.com/global-error-handler-in-a-spring-rest-api)

Sample code:

```
    @ControllerAdvice
    public class GlobalExceptionHandlers {

        private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GlobalExceptionHandlers.class);


        /***************** User Defined Exceptions *************************/

        @ExceptionHandler({ EmployeePartnerNotFoundException.class })
        public ResponseEntity<Object> handleEmployeePartnerNotFoundException(EmployeePartnerNotFoundException ex) {

        logger.error("EmployeePartnerNotFoundException : ", ex);

        ErrorResponse errorResponse = new ErrorResponse("500", ex.getMessage());

        return new ResponseEntity<Object>(errorResponse, new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }

        // other exception handlers

}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's what I ended up doing in the end, along with the reply by Sangam:

Individual Exception handlers worked quite well; Do note there is no need to put these in separate class.

But I still wonder if there is a similar pattern where the application is not Spring MVC?

```
    public ResponseEntity<?> updatePartnerDetails(@PathVariable("employeeId") Long employeeId,
                                                  @RequestBody PersonDetails partnerDto) {
        LOG.info("Updating partner details for employee {}, partner details {}", employeeId, partnerDto);
        validateRequestValues(partnerDto);
        // Try-catches were around this call
        Person partner = PersonMapper.fromPersonDetails(partnerDto);
        employeeService.updateEmployeePartner(employeeId, partner);
        LOG.info("partner details updated for partner id {}", employeeId);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(partner.getId(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.I_AM_A_TEAPOT)  // TODO: BAD_REQUEST
    @ExceptionHandler({EmployeePartnerExistsException.class, EmployeePartnerNotFoundException.class})
    public ResponseEntity<?> employeePartnerError(Exception ex) {
        LOG.error(ex.getMessage());
        return new ResponseEntity<Object>(new ErrorResponse(400, ex.getMessage()), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.I_AM_A_TEAPOT)  // TODO: BAD_REQUEST
    @ExceptionHandler(IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<?> validationError(Exception ex) {
        LOG.error(ex.getMessage());
        return new ResponseEntity<Object>(new ErrorResponse(400, ex.getMessage()), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.I_AM_A_TEAPOT)  // TODO: FORBIDDEN
    @ExceptionHandler(ReadOperationDeniedException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<?> forbidden(Exception ex) {
        LOG.error("User doesn't have permissions to amend employee's details");
        return new ResponseEntity<Object>(new ErrorResponse(403, "User doesn't have permissions to amend employee's details"), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.I_AM_A_TEAPOT)  // TODO: INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public ResponseEntity<?> unspecifiedError(Exception ex) {
        LOG.error("User doesn't have permissions to amend employee's details");
        return new ResponseEntity<Object>(new ErrorResponse(500, "Something went wrong while editing employee's details"), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Comment: ControllerAdvice is better than defining the Exception handlers in the same controller.  because ExceptionHandler annotated method is only active for that particular Controller, not globally for the entire application. Of course adding this to every controller makes it not well suited for a general exception handling mechanism.